# How do I remap the keybindings to change modes in vscode vim extension from insert to normal mode?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

1. How does one change the shortcut to switch between insert mode and normal mode?
2. Where can I find a list of all vim extension shortcuts and their  commands? 
   I searched for them in keyboard shortcuts but you can only search by keybindings which complicates things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I settled on mapping `^ + [` to the command `extension.vim_escape`. Additional detail for the community:

   - Open `keybindings.json`

     - `⇧ + ⌘ + p` or `ctrl + shift + p` by default
     - Enter *Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts*
     - Select the file icon in the top-right corner of the pane:
       [image: file-icon]
   - Add the following JSON object to the list:

     ```json
     {
     "key": "ctrl+[",
     "command": "extension.vim_escape",
     "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl"
     }
     ```
   - Notes:

     - Setting `"vim.useCtrlKeys": true` in `settings.json` might also be required
     - I assume that a different escape sequence could also be used
     - I'm using `vscodevim.vim` version `v1.17.2` on macOS
2. In the keyboard shortcuts UI (not the JSON file), searching for `extension.vim_` showed a list of Vim "Commands" that can be sent to the Vim emulator according to their keybindings

   - For example, after performing the above, searching for `extension.vim_escape` provides the following:
     [image: vim-commands]